# Problem with components after migration project from Flash CS3 to CS4

Tags: flash, actionscript

I start flash as3 project on Flash CS3, about one year ago. After compile it on CS4, I get this error (on Russian):

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Не удается вызвать свойство или метод со ссылкой на объект "null".
    at fl.controls::TextArea/drawLayout()
    at fl.controls::TextArea/draw()
    at fl.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher()
```

But I get this error only in browser (FlashPlayer10), if I run inside Flash CS4 - all works fine.

And I get this error then the MovieClip with TextArea added on stage.

Answer (score 0):

Silly question, 
but is the TextArea component still in the library ?
Try to delete it and drag it again from the Components Panel.

When exactly does the error occur ?
As soon as you access the TextArea ? When you try to retrieve/set the text ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting the error only inside your browser, then the error could be related to the housing HTML/Javascript. Additionally, since it's a null-pointer error, I would suspect the Window size adjustment and (guessing totally) maybe you try to set the TextArea to a null length or width...? On the other hand, object load order might be slightly different. In all cases, you're expecting an object to be not-null that is null. You can track this down in debug mode...

I would try again with SWF Object and see if that works, in all cases. Even if it doesn't solve the problem, you'll need to figure it out for eventual placing of your SWF, so it's time well spent.